# Adding map style at jupyter notebook. Keplergl library

Tags: python, dictionary, jupyter-notebook, output, kepler.gl

I can't to confirm map style at notebook, because don't see the button to approve.

[image]

I fill style `url`, token, name. Bu can't click "Add style" button which appears only in html version"

[image]

I've tried to increase the cell width:

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>.container { width:100% !important; }</style>"))
```

And to display full outputs:

```
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"
```

Nothing helps